# Is it possible to use client side certificates to connect to a SQL Server 2008 database?

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

My problems is as follows. I use a SQL Server 2008 database. I don't want to put db passwords in plain text on my configuration. I know that there is an option to encrypt the `app.config` like the following [article](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2008/04/13/encrypting-passwords-in-a-net-app-config-file.aspx) explains, but in my case I don't think it is sufficiently secure. Someone proposed that I will try to search for a way to use client side certificates to connect the database. I could not find a way to do it and appreciate your help here.

Many thanks,
ikaso

Comment: Can you not use Windows Authentication?

Comment: Currently I use SQL authentication, but it can be changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on comments to the quesion..

If you use "Windows Authentication" then no passwords are needed.

The credentials are taken from the token of the logged in user. The "logged in" user can be

- A human using some app
- IIS App Pool credentials
- Windows Service credentials

So the password entry is done when configuring IIS or the service, or when the human logs in.

This assumes a domain of course...

Comment: Ok. I guess your answer solves my problem, but for completeness it would be nice to know if one could use a client-side certificate to solve this problem.

Comment: @Ikaso: No. You can use client side certs to encrypt *traffic* but not for identification of a user